# first minimum value from given values in C++

Tags: c++, minimum

```
    string result;

    double zpls, zmin, ypls, ymin, xpls, zmin ;

    zpls = 4.2;
    zmin = 0;
    ypls = -2;
    ymin = 4.2;
    xpls = 6;
    xmin = 8;
```

How to find "first minimum positive" among these values and set

```
    result = "+Z";// or wichever value is lowest -z, +Y etc
```

(in C++)

i tried arrays , if else and 
 min(zpls,min(zmin,min(....))) // with `#include <algorithm>`

but could not get it correctly

thanks

Comment: correction : //#include <algorithm>

Comment: If this is an homework assignment please tag so?

Comment: Define what you mean by first none of the data you show us is in an array or other data structure that could have an order. + accept some answers so to persuade people to work out what you are asking

Comment: @mangobug: The use of meta-tags such as homework has been discouraged for a long time now.

Comment: first as the variables appear in order shown from top to bottom

Comment: @Magnus, the homework tag [is considered an exception to the no-meta-tags rule](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have the data in independent variables, you'll need to do an if-else

```
result = ""; // no result yet
double minValue = std::numeric_limits<double>::max( );
if( zplus > 0 && zpls < minValue ) {
  minValue = zpls;
  result = "+Z"
}
if( zmin > 0 && zmin < minValue ) {
  minValue = zmin;
  result = "-Z"
}
```

and so forth, in that pattern. At the end `result` will either have the string you want, or it will be empty (in which case, there were no positive values.)

Here is a complete sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

int main () {
    std::string result;

    double zpls, zmin, ypls, ymin, xpls, xmin ;

    zpls = 4.2;
    zmin = 0;
    ypls = -2;
    ymin = 4.2;
    xpls = 6;
    xmin = 8;

    result = ""; // no result yet
    double minValue = std::numeric_limits<double>::max( );
    if( zpls > 0 && zpls < minValue ) {
      minValue = zpls;
      result = "+Z";
    }
    if( zmin > 0 && zmin < minValue ) {
      minValue = zmin;
      result = "-Z";
    }
    if( ypls > 0 && ypls < minValue ) {
      minValue = ypls;
      result = "+Y";
    }
    if( ymin > 0 && ymin < minValue ) {
      minValue = ymin;
      result = "-Y";
    }

    if( xpls > 0 && xpls < minValue ) {
      minValue = xpls;
      result = "+X";
    }
    if( xmin > 0 && xmin < minValue ) {
      minValue = xmin;
      result = "-X";
    }


    std::cout << "The first mininum positive element is: " << result << "\n";
}
```

Comment: i have already tried this and also six temp variables to <double>::max() and comparing them .. all i get is minimum value ..which is not sufficient to set FLAG "+Z"

Comment: Do you see the line in my code that reads `result = "+Z"`? That is where you set the flag.

Comment: @Raj, I notice that you have asked five questions, but haven't accepted any of the answers. Please go through your questions. Please upvote (click the up-arrow) the answers that help you, and then accept (click the check-mark) the answers that help you the most.

Answer (score 0):

if you run [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) on any collection of numbers, the "first minimum positive" will simply be the "first positive".

If you run [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) on that sorted collection, you can find that first positive.

Comment: Though adjusting the algorithm instead of the sort criteria is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Don't adjust algorithms. The algorithm is clear ("find minimum"). Adjust the search criteria instead, and stay in O(n) realm.

#### Code.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    // std::min_element()
    std::vector<float> vec;

    vec.push_back(0);
    vec.push_back(-1);
    vec.push_back(-2);
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(4);

    auto cmp = [](float lhs, float rhs) {
        const bool lz = lhs < 0,
                   rz = rhs < 0;
        if (lz && rz) return lhs < rhs;
        if (lz) return false;
        if (rz) return true;
        return lhs < rhs;
    };

    const float mp = *std::min_element (vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);        
    std::cout << mp << '\n';

    // demonstration of our comparison
    sort (vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);
    for (auto it=vec.begin(), end=vec.end(); it!=end; ++it)
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

#### Output.

```
0
0 2 4 -1 -2
```

#### Explanation.

Our sorting function is encoded in `cmp`. It checks the signs of its operands. If both are negative, the bigger one wins. If only the LHS is negative, then RHS is automatically preferred in the sorting. On the opposite, if the RHS is negative, LHS is preferred. Of both are positive, we fall back to the normal order.

Nice thing is that this runs exactly one time over the range and in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

are you *really* need sepearte variables. Why not to design like this:

```
enum Tags
{
 ZPlus,
 ZMinus,
 Etc
};

const std::string [] names = {"z+", "z-", "etc" }

int values[3];
```

and insted of `zmin = -3;` you get `values[ZMinus] = -3;`
then you can find minimum index in `values` array and `return names[minimumIndex];`